# Do jungle enchantment passives add to the origional item's passives, or replace them?

Tags: league-of-legends

For example, if I purchaced Stalker's Blade, which has Chilling Smite as it's passive, and then used it to craft Runic Echoes, which has Echo as it's passive, could I still use Chilling Smite? If not, does this make Runic Echoes a downgrade in some situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The whole purpose of Enchantments is to provide bonus effects, so all the original item's passives will be preserved.**

From the [wiki page on Enchantments](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Enchantment):

> An Enchantment is a purchasable upgrade for certain classes of items that grants them an **additional** effect.

As per your example, you could purchase the Runic Echoes Enchantment on a Stalker's Blade and still have Chilling Smite - it is in no way a downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer isn't wrong per say, it's very inaccurate.

You are correct to assume that when you sell an item you lose its passives and stats. It happens with Seeker's Armguard, and it happens with Stalker's blade (and several other items).

Seeker's Armguard is the best example. It grants Ability Power and Armor per unit killed, however, if you upgrade it to Zhonyas Hourglass you lose the passive Armor. So technically you will lose the Chilling Smite ability.

However, in practice, you keep it. That's because while you lose the item that provides the Chilling Smite ability, you're getting a second item with that very same passive (the Runic Echoes Enchantment).

**Short answer, you can still use Chilling Smite.**

Comment: While I understand your point (and yes my answer probably isn't any more accurate), I'm questioning whether it is entirely correct to refer to the Enchanted items as different items completely. I have never seen Enchanted items listed anywhere; rather, the Enchantments themselves are listed without any base item. I guess it's up to the perspective you take on it, really.

Comment: They're treated as actual items by the API. I only included this answer because this question is very similar to the Zhonya's / Sterak's Gage situation, but the practical result in them is different

Comment: Ok, fair enough.